# android cannot resolve method runonuithread

Tags: android

My app should connect to a server and receive data from it. But it's not working because of this error:

```
android cannot resolve method runOnUiThread(anonymous java.lang.Runnable)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Code:

```
package com.example.chudnofsky.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.190.47");
                        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 15000);

                        PrintWriter out = null;
                        BufferedReader in = null;

                        //out = new PrintWriter(String.valueOf(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))));
                        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                        if (socket.isConnected()) {
                            String text = "";
                            String finalText = "";
                            while ((text = in.readLine()) != null) {
                                finalText += text;
                            }
                            WriteText(textview, finalText);
                            Log.d("TCP", "Connected");
                        }

                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();


        }
    });

}
public void WriteText(final TextView textView, final String value ){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textView.setText(value);
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: i do not see declaration of runOnUIThread method?

Comment: @MaciejSikora for thread safety. so I can connect and receive data at the same time. `public void WriteText(final TextView textView, final String value ){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textView.setText(value);
        }
    });
}`

Answer (score 1):

inside the method do this :

```
new Handler().post(runnable);
```

and define the runnable like this :

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {   
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {  
            public void run()  {   
               textView.setText(value);
            } 
    });
```

Comment: @A.Sherry Try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34970752/7551190) then. It worked for me